# IE 11 on Windows7 getting "this page can't be displayed" or page comes as HTML

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I have  Windows 7 and IE 11 I have a few problems:

1. Sometimes I get :  "this page can't be displayed " when asked to search to search for page
2. Also sometimes Hotmail comes as HTML file, and some times other sites come up as HTML.
3. Some links from sites or hotmail come up as " this can't be displayed"or it may come up as HTML

Answer (score 1):

Is this a new problem or have you been experiencing it for a while?

I suggest you download Firefox or Chrome as a test to see whether the same problem occurs with one of these browsers. If so then it sounds like it's a network connectivity or web site problem. If not then there may be a problem with IE11's settings (as a last resort, it may be worth resetting them to the defaults via `Internet Options` | `Advanced` tab | `Reset...`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which, in my case, had a very simple solution once found.

I use ie 11, windows 7 on a 64bit computer. I tried every solution I could find and nothing worked. Disabled add ons, editing the registry, removed ie 11, installed ie 10, every "solution" I could find. I reinstalled an old utility program I had so I could clean up my system. This actually resulted in showing me what was happening. I noticed on several legitimate sites I would get a message telling me there was a problem listed as "(8 to 10 numbers)webhostoid.com. BINGO!!!!. This led to the solution. After a search to find out what this is, I knew the problem.

At some point while downloading some software there was a "tag-a-long" program known as Genius Box. I deleted all history, cookies and everything before closing ie, went to control panel - programs and features - and removed Genius Box.

I tried to load the problem web page expecting the worse but I had the problem solved after about 6 months.